# gwt anchor tag not anchoring

Tags: gwt, anchor

Why does the browser not scroll to the anchor?
url:*http://localhost:8080/index.html#myAnchor3*

```
this.anchor1.setName("myAnchor1");
this.add(this.anchor1);
this.anchor2.setName("myAnchor2");
this.add(this.anchor2);
this.anchor3.setName("myAnchor3");
this.add(this.anchor3);
```

Is it because the anchor is created after the page has finished loading, so the browser doesn't see the anchor when it tries to scroll to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to override the onLoad method, and call scrollIntoView there, otherwise it was trying to scroll to an object that wasn't added to the DOM yet.

```
public class Foo extends Widget
{
  Foo(){
  }

  @Override
  protected void onLoad(){
    super.onLoad();
    getElement().scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.anchor.setName("myAnchor");
this.add(this.anchor);
location.hash = '#myAnchor';
```

And yes, you are right, your anchor was created/inserted after the page load, so well.....

Comment: where is location.hash in scope? location is in scope, but it only has accessor methods, no direct access or setter methods.

Comment: @antony: Are you saying it doesn;t work for you. It does for me. In full, it is "window.location.hash" (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533775%28VS.85%29.aspx). It can be read/assigned.

Comment: ah, you jumped down to javascript.

Comment: @anthony: ermm, everything you coded is javascript, ain't it? If you want the hash to be dynamic based on the one supplied in the URL, then set "location.hash = location.hash;" after you created the anchors.

Comment: @anthony: My apology, how could I miss that. If your anchor is defined before it is rendered to the browser, it should work.Did you check the HTML markup? You should see a '<a name="myAchor"....'

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Element.scrollIntoView(), which not only will scroll the window, but any scrollable container in the DOM hierarchy that holds the element.

Comment: looks promising, I'll try it tonight.

Comment: haven't gotten this to work yet, but not convinced I'm not doing something wrong yet.

Comment: I was trying to scroll to an element that wasn't added to the DOM yet. Restructuring some code...