# gwt anchor without update history stack

Tags: gwt

i have a page with lots of hrefs link to arbitrary points of the page, say when i click the link `<a href="#b">B</a>` i should go to the point B. however i don't wanna update the history stack when i click the link, which by default will be udpate to `/index.html#B`. i can use g:Anchor instead of hyperlink to avoid updating history stack, but how can i really go to the point B in my page? my code looks like this:
index.ui.xml

```
      <g:Anchor ui:field="_a">A</g:Anchor>
      ...
      <a name="a"></a>
        <h3>Point A</h3>
      <a name="b"></a>
        <h3>Point B</h3>
      ...
```

index.java

```
@UiField
Anchor _a;
@UiHandler("_a") 
void onClickA(ClickEvent e){
    //how to goto point A in the page ??
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Window.scrollTo() method ?

Comment: i tried but it didn't work(didn't scroll at all): onClickA(ClickEvent e) {Element aElem = container.getElementById("a"); if (aElem != null) { Window.scrollTo(aElem.getAbsoluteLeft(), aElem.getAbsoluteTop();}}

Answer (score 0):

What you possible can do is call: `_a.getElement().scrollIntoView();`. This scroll to the anchor such that it is at least visible.

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this is already Discussed,**

[gwt anchor tag not anchoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586463/gwt-anchor-tag-not-anchoring)

[GWT clickable link (anchor) without href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356543/gwt-clickable-link-anchor-without-href)